# I cannot connect to my own Team Fortress 2 server? Why?

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2, hosting

Recently, I have been encountering an unusual problem with a testing TF2 server that I'm running on my local system. Namely, my client is completely unable to connect to the server. It does not appear on the LAN tab, and connecting it through `connect localhost:27015` does absolutely nothing but time out.

The server is set up through `srcds`, with the following startup shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
tf2/srcds_run -console \
    -game tf \
    -nohltv \
    +randommap \
    +maxplayers 24
```

The config file of the server is as follows:

```
hostname "Local_Dev_Server"
sv_contact "hello@hello.hello"
sv_pausable 1
sv_stats 0
sv_region 1
fps_max 600
sv_allowupload 1
sv_allowdownload 1
```

The server is (obviously) running on my local computer, primarily for development purposes. The server itself is running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and is starting up normally. The console reports no strange errors other than the usual SRCDS warnings and/or irrelevant mod errors.

The server itself binds to port 27015:

```
Network: IP 127.0.1.1, mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27015 SV / 27005 CL
```

Attempts to connect directly (with the `connect 127.0.1.1:27015` command) return this in the console:

```
] connect 127.0.1.1:27015
WARNING: Port 27015 was unavailable - bound to port 27016 instead
WARNING: Port 27005 was unavailable - bound to port 27006 instead
Network: IP 127.0.1.1, mode MP, dedicated No, ports 27016 SV / 27006 CL
m_face->glyph->bitmap.width is 0 for ch:32 TF2
m_face->glyph->bitmap.width is 0 for ch:32 TF2
m_face->glyph->bitmap.width is 0 for ch:32 Verdana
Connecting to 127.0.1.1:27015...
Retrying 127.0.1.1:27015...
Retrying 127.0.1.1:27015...
Retrying 127.0.1.1:27015...
Connection failed after 4 retries.
```

No entry shows in the server logs. `netstat -tulpn | grep 27015` returns the following, showing the server is running and bound to the port:

```
tcp   0   0   127.0.1.1:27015   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  26665/srcds_linux
udp   0   0   0.0.0.0:27015     0.0.0.0:*          26665/srcds_linux
```

My system's firewall is blocking connections from the world (as this is only a local development server), but connections to/from the `127.0.0.0/8` subnet are all globally permitted. Similarly, debug utilities like `netcat` and `telnet` are able to connect to these ports, showing that they are in fact bound and accessible locally.

I've confirmed that this problem happens with both `sv_lan 0` and `sv_lan 1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `sv_lan 1`? It shouldn't be necessary afair, but it might help.

Comment: @Riker I'll give `sv_lan 1` a shot after work, though I seem to remember it causing my server to crash on map switch.

Comment: Huh, never done that for me.

Comment: I can't help but notice that the server says it's binding to port 27016 because 27015 is currently unavailable.

Comment: @Powerlord The client is saying that. The actual server is binding to 27015. Does the client also need to be on 27015?

Comment: What happens if you try connecting to port 27016?

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem: Try connecting to 192.x.x.x instead of 172.y.y.y. (where 192.x.x.x is your internal IP).

Comment: @Riker Connecting to my NAT local-inside IP works just fine. Interesting. Is there any reason it would work with that but not a loopback IP? Similarly, can this be used to re-add the server to the LAN list (just for convenience's sake)?

Comment: @KazWolfe It doesn't work with sv_lan 1, right? I have no clue.  And for the latter, I think so, yea.

Comment: @Riker It does not work with sv_lan 1, and is still not showing up in the LAN list. At least it's sort of working now, though.

Comment: @KazWolfe huh, that's odd. Sadly, the valve wiki is almost barren, nothing helpful there.

Answer (score 1):

AIUI the *client* needs to listen on some port (usually 27015) on the loopback interface (why, I don't know). When you try to put the *server* on that same port, the client ends up moving to a different port, and for some reason, the two of them get confused. I run my server on my LAN IP, and then use `iptables` to control access. When working with closed-source software, it's usually easiest to manage security elsewhere :)

Answer (score -3):

A localhost address looks like this: `192.168.*.*`

Press your <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open run and open up cmd.

type `ipconfig /all` and look for your ipv4 address.

Once you've got that use <kbd>~</kbd> to open console and use

```
connect 192.168.*.*
```

With the * being the numbers cmd showed. It shouldn't be necessary to assign a port.

Comment: `zsh: command not found: ipconfig.`

Comment: `localhost` is actually `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @KazWolfe use $ ifconfig -a if you are using linux to find ipv4

Comment: Local IP: 10.137.42.29. If I connect to that, it works. However, this still does not explain why my system can not connect to localhost (loopback) IPs, or show the server in the LAN list. While this works, it's still a massive pain to have to look this up every time I want to work on the server, especially as my network has a very low DHCP expiry threshold.

Comment: maybe you have bound a dynamic ip for your system to your router. see if you can set your local ip to be static